# PHP Preg_Match Help

Tags: php, preg-match

I'm having problems getting the URL from a list. I need to call the script script.php?id=**31** and have it print out the correct resulting url http://site.com/page.php?id=**31**&section=2 without the (`url=` and `,`).

I'm using `print_r` in the sample because `$url[0]` and `$url[1]` didn't have the result.

Thanks

```
<?php
$id=$_REQUEST["id"];
$links="
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=22&section=1,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=10&section=8,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=31&section=2,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=15&section=3,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=16&section=7,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=12&section=5,
";
preg_match("/url\=(.*?)&id\=$id&(.*?),/is", $links, $url);
print_r($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split up your string literal to make it easier:

```
$id = 31;
preg_match('/url=((?:.*?)[?&]id=' . $id . '&.*),/im', $subject, $regs);
echo $regs[1]; // this will be 'http://site.com/page.php?id=$31&section=3'
```

### EDIT

Improved version that supports `url=http://site.com/page.php?id=31,` (without the `&` after the id)

```
$id = 1;
preg_match('/url=((?:.*?)[?&]id=' . $id . '[^0-9](?<![0-9]).*),/im', $subject, $regs)
echo $regs[1]; // this will be 'http://site.com/page.php?id=$31&section=3'
```

### EDIT AGAIN

WOW, i meant to put `$regs[1]`, not `$subject[1]`, that was dumb :-P

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! I tried and it didn't work so I tried some tweaks and its stlll now working. Preg_match is so picky.

Comment: haha. I feel like an idiot. It was missing the ; at the end. Its printing the correct result now but its adding strange chars.

Comment: Bob it partially did. The url its printing out is modified with characters I don't have in the url.

Comment: With your 2nd edit code its printing out: site.com/page.php?id=15§ion=3 when it needs to print out the correct url of http://site.com/page.php?id=15&section=3

Comment: It has the h t t p part but stackoverflow is chopping it from my comment. So the only problem nows is for some reason your code is adding a § to the url.

Comment: `&sect` is an HTML entity that makes §.  so where are you using this url.  If you are just outputting it to the HTML doc, it will that that is encoded.  Try printing it using htmlspecialchars (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't `/url\=(.*?)&id\=$id&(.*?),/is` be `/url\=(.*?)[?&]id\=$id&(.*?),/is`? You're trying to match something until `&id=`, although you have `?id=` in your URLs.

Comment: `(?:&|\?)` can be more easily writted as `[?&]`

Comment: @Bob Fincheimer, fixed it, tx.

Comment: Opps! That was a typo. It was supposed to be ? instead of &. I changed it and it still didn't work. Going to try Bob's code now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];

$links="
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=22&section=1,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=10&section=8,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=31&section=2,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=31&section=3,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=16&section=7,
url=http://site.com/page.php?id=12&section=5,
";
preg_match_all('/(url=.*?id='.$id.'&.*?),/im', $links, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

for($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++)
{
$link = preg_replace('/(url=|,)/im', '', $result[1][$i]);
echo  $link;
}
```

Assuming that $id is 31, will output:

```
http://site.com/page.php?id=31&section=2
http://site.com/page.php?id=31&section=3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way:

```
$links=str_replace(',', '', $links);
$links=explode(array(',', 'url='), $links);
preg_match("/(.*?)&id\=$id&(.*?)/", $links, $url);
print_r($url);
```

I think this should work.

Comment: Thanks JanL! I tried explode but still ran into problems with preg_match getting the correct url. It was just giving me the first url no matter what.